# JQuery - jScrollPane - Dynamic height stays fixed

Tags: jquery, css, jscrollpane, javascript

I'm trying to use jScrollPane for have a scroll in a dynamic div, but I'm having some troubles...

Here is my structure

```
<div id="DynamicDivHeightAndWidth">
   <div id="Content">
       <div id="TextContent"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I only have this CSS propreties (only for the principal div that must have a dynamic height and a dynamic width)

```
.DynamicDivHeightAndWidth{
color:#FFF;
float:left;
margin-left:30px;
-webkit-border-radius:20px;
-moz-border-radius:20px;
background-color:#000;
border:solid #FF6C00 3px;
display:none;
z-index:10;
overflow:hidden;
width:21%;
height:21%;}
```

My jScrollPane is declared like so :

```
$(function()
        {
            $('#Content').each(
                function()
                {
                    $(this).jScrollPane(
                        {
                            showArrows: $(this).is('.arrow')
                        }
                    );
                    var api = $(this).data('jsp');
                    var throttleTimeout;
                    $(window).bind(
                        'resize',
                        function()
                        {
                            if ($.browser.msie) {
                                // IE fires multiple resize events while you are dragging the browser window which
                                // causes it to crash if you try to update the scrollpane on every one. So we need
                                // to throttle it to fire a maximum of once every 50 milliseconds...
                                if (!throttleTimeout) {
                                    throttleTimeout = setTimeout(
                                        function()
                                        {
                                            api.reinitialise();
                                            throttleTimeout = null;
                                        },
                                        50
                                    );
                                }
                            } else {
                                api.reinitialise();
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            )

        });
```

Now my problem is that my "DynamicDivHeightAndWidth" have a dynamic width, BUT the height stay in fix and I don't know why ?

I've tried many issues, but still doesn't work...

Thank for your help ^^

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your html and body heights to 100%
Also just check your CSS you define your dynamic div as a class and not a id

Comment: *the div have an id, it's the class name :-) I forget to change it before to post it sorry :-)

Comment: Thanks for the jsFiddle, but stille not working with the configuration :-( Does it work for you ?